# QTransform show/hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, hide, rotation, show

I'm using puppybits jQuery plugin QTransform to rotate/animate an element (https://github.com/puppybits/QTransform). I have every thing working except for the show after rotation is complete.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rotatehs').hide();
    $('#bkgimg')
        .css('translate', 100)
        .css('rotate', -1)
        .animate({rotate: '+=360deg'}, 4000)
--------------> add show after rotate complete ('#rotatehs') here <--------------
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a callback to the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rotatehs').hide();
    $('#bkgimg')
        .css('translate', 100)
        .css('rotate', -1)
        .animate({rotate: '+=360deg'}, 4000, function() {
            $('#rotatehs').show();
        });
});
```